# SQL - Group By where rows have the most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having the following tables and I was wondering how to do a query on it.

Table Recipe

```
ID | Name
0  | Apple pie
1  | Pizza
```

Table Ingredient

```
RecipeID  | Timestamp | Name    | Price
0         | 10-2-2014 | Apple   | 1.20
0         | 7-2-2014  | Apple   | 1.14
0         | 9-2-2014  | Flour   | 2.00
1         | 9-2-2014  | Tomato  | 1.12
```

How can I do a Group By RecipeID on this so I get the following results

```
RecipeID  | Name      | Total_Latest_Ingredient_Price
0         | Apple Pie | 3.20
1         | Pizza     | 1.12
```

The idea is that the Query should only take the ingredients with the latest dates. So that the price for an apple from 10-2-2014 will be taken and not the one (or both) from 7-2-2014. So only the latest dates.

This might be a tough cookie ( or not! ) but I hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the combination of `(RecipeID, Timestamp, Name)` is unique on the `Ingredient` table, and assuming that column named `Timestamp` is stored in a canonical form (e.g. either MySQL DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP datatype or a character datatype with format such that a comparison of values will always yield a "latest" Timestamp value...

The normative pattern is to use an inline view to retrieve the "latest" `Timestamp`, and then use a JOIN operation to retrieve the entire row.

```
SELECT g.RecipeID
     , SUM(g.Price) AS `Total_Latest_Ingredient_Price`
  FROM Ingredient g
  JOIN (SELECT h.RecipeID
             , h.Name
             , MAX(h.Timestamp) AS `Timestamp`
          FROM Ingredient h
         GROUP
            BY h.RecipeID
             , h.Name
       ) i
    ON i.RecipeID  = g.RecipeID
   AND i.Name      = g.Name
   AND i.Timestamp = g.Timestamp
 GROUP BY g.RecipeID
```

The inline view aliased as **i** gets the "latest" `Timestamp` (assuming, again, that `Timestamp` column is canonical form, such that the "maximum" value is guaranteed to be the "latest" value. This will be true if datatype of the column named `Timestamp` is MySQL `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`.)

The outer query references rows returned by **i**, and performs a JOIN operation to retrieve the entire row from the table (aliased as **g**) to get the related Price.

To get the `Name` column from the Recipe table, we'd add a JOIN operation to that table...

```
SELECT g.RecipeID
     , r.Name
     , SUM(g.Price) AS `Total_Latest_Ingredient_Price`
  FROM Ingredient g
  JOIN (SELECT h.RecipeID
             , h.Name
             , MAX(h.Timestamp) AS `Timestamp`
          FROM Ingredient h
         GROUP
            BY h.RecipeID
             , h.Name
       ) i
    ON i.RecipeID  = g.RecipeID
   AND i.Name      = g.Name
   AND i.Timestamp = g.Timestamp
  JOIN Recipe r
    ON r.ID = g.RecipeID 
 GROUP BY g.RecipeID
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I'd do it (and did it) too.

Comment: I neglected to add the `GROUP BY` clause on the outermost query; that's been corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

VMai's query above is close, but you need to filter the latest date... so selecting the max timestamp for a given recipe/ingredient and join that back to your table. You should also be able do this with a WHERE clause, but the inner join to the Ingredient table (with max time stamp by recipe/ingredient) was more straightforward, so I just went with that

```
 SELECT
        I.RecipeID,
        R.Name,
        SUM(Price) AS Total_Ingredient_Price
    FROM
        Recipe R
    INNER JOIN
        Ingredient I
    ON
        R.ID = I.RecipeID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Timestamp) AS latest, RecipeID, Name FROM Ingredient GROUP BY RecipieID, Name) AS c
    ON I.RecipeID = c.RecipeID
    AND I.Name = c.Name
    AND I.TimeStamp = c.latest
    GROUP BY
        I.RecipeID,
        R.Name
```

Comment: .+1 ... assuming that MAX(Timestamp) will retrieve the "latest" value.

Comment: Agreed. If the timestamp is not an actual date value, but rather a string (for example) then this won't work. But converting data table is pretty straightforward in most cases and the logic itself would be the same, with the exception of the data conversion.

Comment: Data wouldn't necessarily need to be converted in the table. This query will work if it's stored canonical, e.g. always in exactly 'YYYY-MM-DD' format; if value is stored as m/d/yyyy, then we could use a `STR_TO_DATE` function within the query..., e.g. `MAX(STR_TO_DATE(d.Timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y'))`

Answer (score 0):

That's an easy one:
You sum up the prices of the ingredients by recipe:

```
SELECT
    I.RecipeID,
    R.Name,
    SUM(Price) AS Total_Latest_Ingredient_Price
FROM
    Recipe R
INNER JOIN
    Ingredient I
ON
    R.ID = I.RecipeID
GROUP BY
    I.RecipeID,
    R.Name
```

Comment: Mmm it looks good! I just wonder, where in your query do you account for the timestamp differences that might be there? I mean the Apple example that had it's price meassured at two moments. And only take the most recent one?

Comment: This query will not keep the latest price, though.... in particular it would sum Apple twice, in the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation:

```
select a.recipeid, c.name, sum(a.price) total_latest_ingredient_price
from ingredient a
join (
  select recipeid, name, max(timestamp) m
  from ingredient 
  group by recipeid, name) b on a.recipeid = b.recipeid and a.name = b.name and a.timestamp = b.m
join recipe c on a.recipeid = c.id
group by a.recipeid;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3977c/2)

Comment: think you need to add b.name in your group by :-)

Comment: @evanv, I think they refer to the same thing?

Comment: You are absolutely right. But instead of b.name in your query, it should be c.name (I was confusing a sum by ingredients vs a sum by recipe). In this case, a.recipeid, *c*.name would be ideal.... and a group by a.recipe (or use c.recipe for consistency... either way, won't make much difference... maybe use c instead, since it's likely a primary index, but otherwise no real difference either way)

Comment: @evanv, oops. Thanks for catching that. It's corrected.